# Which Id should I set when I am using a bridge table?

Tags: java, rest, setter

So I am working on my first RESTful API in java (with IntelliJ), but I came across a problem that I don't know how to solve.
When this is my bridge table:

[image: My bridge table]

Which Id do I set in my controller.

**This is my controller:**

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/coalitionparties")
public class CoalitionPartyController {
    @Autowired
    CoalitionPartyService coalitionPartyService;
    @GetMapping("")
    public List<CoalitionParty> list(){
        return coalitionPartyService.listAllCoalitionParties();
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<CoalitionParty> get(@PathVariable Integer id){
        try{
            CoalitionParty coalitionParty = coalitionPartyService.getCoalitionParty(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<CoalitionParty>(coalitionParty, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<CoalitionParty>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    @PostMapping("/")
    public void add(@RequestBody CoalitionParty coalitionParty){

        coalitionPartyService.saveCoalitionParty(coalitionParty);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody CoalitionParty coalitionParty, @PathVariable Integer id){
        try{
            CoalitionParty existCoalitionParty = coalitionPartyService.getCoalitionParty(id);
            coalitionParty.setId(id);
            coalitionPartyService.saveCoalitionParty(coalitionParty);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
        coalitionPartyService.deleteCoalition(id);
    }
}
```

Which Id do I set with the `@PutMapping`in the line(coalition, party or user):

```
 coalitionParty.setId(id);
```

Can you also explain why, because I am pretty new at it.
Thanks!

Comment: The primary key of your junction (bridge) table is actually the combination of all 3 id columns, so strictly speaking your endpoint should receive 3 values.  But, there is a possible smell here, because Hibernate/JPA is supposed to handle junction tables under the hood, so maybe your API design should change.

Comment: How would I need to change it in order to let Hibernate or JPA handle the junction tables (or do you have a link to a good video about it?)